# Query Data from Another Backendless App

Tags: backendless

Does backendless support querying data from another Backendless App Table? If yes how.

If I have Backendless App called Music with Table songs and I have another App called Movie. I want to query the song table from the Movie app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You gonna need to call `Backendless.initApp(context, {another_app_id}, {another_app_secret_key}, v1)` before each call to a different application. This way you'll be able to talk to any number of apps.

Answer (score -1):

#Save

```
            useres useres = new useres();
            useres.setName("Amin");
            useres.setId("DOREH");
            useres.setScore("20");
            useres.setData("2016.12.24");
            Backendless.Persistence.save(useres, new AsyncCallback<com.example.amin.bback.useres>() {
                @Override
                public void handleResponse(useres response)
                {
                   Log.d(  "Register",response.toString());

                }

                @Override
                public void handleFault(BackendlessFault fault)
                {
                    Log.d(  "Register faild ",fault.toString());
                }
            });
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but the question was about accessing data from two different apps not two tables within an app.