# Share User Table between Several Backendless App

Tags: backendless

I want to be able to share the User table between several Backendless apps, so the same user can be related to objects in all of the apps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's impossible to share anything between applications in Backendless.
The only thing you can do is to [export](https://backendless.com/feature-70-export-application-data-settings-data-tables-geo-points/) and [import](https://backendless.com/documentation/manage/mgmt_import.htm) the table from one app to another.

Comment: What about using one backendless app to manage the user login and another bakcendless app for the mobile application. Then connect to the login app to authenticate the user and get the objectID and then connect to the mobile app using this technique (http://stackoverflow.com/a/39145875/2330272) of connecting to multiple apps. We can then use the users objectD in the mobile app.

Comment: @BarryMSIH you can do anything you like if you find a way to make it work (and I see you've probably found already).